# Setting a new / override shippingAddress via axios

Tags: craft3, javascript, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am trying to change/set a customers shippingAddress via `axios`

It does work e.g. for setting the `shippingMethod` or the quantity for a product. However if i want to set a new `shippingAddress` the `axios post` fails with a `500 status`

This is my axios post request:

```
updateShipping() {
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-CSRF-Token': window.Craft.csrfToken,
            },
            data: qs.stringify({
                shippingMethodHandle: 'standardShipping', //works
                shippingSameAsBilling: false, // wont work
                shippingAddressId: 'new', // wont work, also tried an existing
                shippingAddress: {
                   firstName: 'test',
                   ...
                },
            }),
            url: '/actions/commerce/cart/update-cart',
        };
        axios(options)
            .then(response => {...})
            .catch(error => {...});
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled over the old questions, this is how it works:

```
updateShipping() {
        const options = {
            method: 'post',
            url: '/actions/commerce/cart/update-cart',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': window.Craft.csrfToken,
            },
            data: qs.stringify({
                shippingMethodHandle: 'standardShipping',
                shippingSameAsBilling: 0,
                shippingAddressId: 123, // remove if it doesn't exists or is new
                shippingAddress: {
                   id: '', // only needed if address is new
                   firstName: 'test',
                   ...
                },
            }),
        };
        axios(options)
            .then(response => {...})
            .catch(error => {...});
    },
```